# 2 routers and want windows to not use a network

Tags: ip, router

Gonna use 'ROUTER ONE' and 'ROUTER TWO', for my examples.
I have two routers, one on wireless one on ethernet. Both have different names. I want windows to just use the internet connection on ROUTER ONE and not use the connection on ROUTER TWO, but I still want to access ROUTER TWO's IP. At the moment to use the network I have to unplug the cable, as I get on the site I want, then the OTHER router takes me too another network saying that the connection is unavailable.
So then, what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router names are irrelevant, all that matters is their IP addresses. You can tell a computer which router to use by setting it gateway address to that router's internal IP address. You can do that in the DHCP settings if you want it applied network wide.

As far as accessing both routers it all depends on how your network is set up both physically and its IP scheme. If both routers are on the same physical network and IP scheme you should be able to access them. If they are on the same physical network but on different IP schemes you can assign a second IP address to a computer that is compatible with the second scheme so you will be able to access the second router.

Comment: Please could you instruct me on how to do this?

Comment: I would need to know a lot more about your setup before I can provide any useful advise. Start by the IP addresses of the two routers and how they are connected to each other (if they are).

Comment: @SunKnight0, you should research First Hop Redundancy Protocols (FHRP). As Brendan writes, it all depends on your network topology.